# Unity virtual joystick - jarring movement

Tags: unity, camera, joystick

I'm creating an infinite flyer game in which you control the plane using a mobile joystick. There are two controls one to rotate the plane and the other to move the plane. While rotating the plane there is a lot of jarring if I use Time.deltatime. There is no jarring when I don't use Time.deltatime. This is the line of code that use Time.deltatime - transform.rotation = _initialRotation * Quaternion.Euler(_pitch*Time.deltaTime,-_yaw*Time.deltaTime, 0).

Here is the code in the Move script:

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{       
public Joystick joystick;
public Joystick joystick1;
float rotateVertical;
float rotateHorizontal;

public float sensitivity;
Quaternion _initialRotation;
float _pitch, _yaw;

float moveHorizontal;
float moveVertical;

void Start()
{
    _initialRotation = transform.rotation;
}
void Update()
{               
    _pitch = _pitch + joystick.Vertical * sensitivity;
    _yaw = _yaw - joystick.Horizontal * sensitivity;
   
    transform.rotation = _initialRotation * Quaternion.Euler(_pitch*Time.deltaTime,-_yaw*Time.deltaTime, 0) ;

    transform.Translate(moveHorizontal * Time.deltaTime, moveVertical * Time.deltaTime, 0);
 }
}
```

There is also a camerafollow script attached.

```
[SerializeField] Transform target;
public Vector3 defaultDist = new Vector3(0f, 0, 7.5f);
[SerializeField] float distDamp = .1f;
public Vector3 velocity = Vector3.one;

Transform myT;

void Awake()
{
    myT = transform;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    SmoothFollow();
}

void SmoothFollow()
{
    Vector3 toPos = target.position + (target.rotation * defaultDist);      
    Vector3 curPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(myT.position, toPos,ref velocity ,distDamp);
    myT.position = curPos ;
    myT.LookAt(target, target.up);
}
```

Comment: My intuition is to use [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html).

Comment: Multiplying by deltaTime is not appropriate here, because you're not integrating a rate of rotation over a time duration. You're setting an absolute deflection relative to the initial orientation. If you multiply by deltaTime here you effectively magnify your joystick sensitivity on long frames and dull it on short frames, making your deflection amount jitter with the framerate. Did you mean to accumulate rotation over time? Or did you mean to omit this multiplication?

Comment: @Theraot , I tried using fixedupdate but whats happening is that on a phone with less processing speed the rotation is slow and on a phone with higher processing speed, the rotation is very fast. And if I use, time.deltatime then the camera starts jarring.

Comment: @DMGregory , I want to be able to have the same speed of rotation irrrespective of device. Without the time.deltatime, the plane rotates very quickly on a phone with higher processing speed and very slowly on a phone with lower processing speed. If I use time.deltatime, then it leads to jarring motion.